# How can my iOS app animate a sequence of colors?

Tags: ios, animation, colors

I have a pre-defined sequence of colors and their durations (ms) that I would like to display in order (animate?) in a subview. In Android, I can use addFrame() with an AnimationDrawable to create an animation object. Is there something similar that will do this for me in iOS? (The total duration must be the sum of the individual color durations.) Thanks!

Comment: Do you need to be able to cancel / pause? Just run the animation once? Have you tried anything?

Comment: No, just run once and stop with no cancel/pause. Sorry, I'm in the planning stage right now, and really have little experience with iOS.

Comment: Uiview animation. Cf http://www.raywenderlich.com/2454/uiview-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-use-uiview-animation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways you could do this. One example:

1. Loop over your colours and durations, say they are in an array of dictionaries (not required)
2. Keep a count of the duration so far
3. On each iteration, create an animation using `+ UIView animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:` where the delay is the accumulated duration, the duration is the duration for this iteration and in the animation block:
4. The animation block sets the `backgroundColor` of the view

This approach has limitations as you can't stop or pause it.

Alternatively, use the completion block to trigger the next step of the animation. Now you can check if you should be stopping, and you don't need to accumulate the duration.

Or, use a `CAPropertyAnimation` key path animation. Now you can cancel at any point in the animation and you have full control over the speed and style of transition between colours.

Comment: Thanks. I like the first option, but how many total animateWithDurations can I start at once? I may need (gulp) over a thousand. Also, could using the completion block to trigger the next step cause the sequence to last longer than it should? Therefore, is your third alternative (key path animation) the way to go?

Comment: 1000! I wouldn't use the first option for more than a handful of colours. The `CAPropertyAnimation` will be best because you will need to stop the animation cleanly at some point if it's that long...

Comment: Starting the next animation from the completion block would likely result in a very short slip in between each animation. How short are your durations?

Comment: Yes, the durations could be very short (e.g. 33ms). Wouldn't CAPropertyAnimation key path animation be more precise?

Comment: Yes, it would. Why so short durations? What is the colour animation for? iOS isn't a real time operating system so you can't guarantee the accuracy of any approach...

Comment: Just to be clear, I could use a keyframe animation with kCAAnimationDiscrete and set the animation duration to the total duration, then iOS would space the colors evenly as long as all color durations are equal, right? How would I do it if the color durations could be different?

Comment: Use the subclass, `CAKeyframeAnimation`, and supply `values` and `keyTimes`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49008/discussion-between-scottyb-and-wain)

Comment: Using CAKeyframeAnimation on the view background worked perfectly. Just had to figure out how to make the keyTimes fit between 0.0 and 1.0.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be using a UIView object, and setting the background color for a certain duration. If the duration is the same you can use an NSTimer to fire repeatedly, setting the view to a new color each time.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple example of animation using completion handler. `_durations` is an array of `NSNumber` objects representing color durations. `_colors` - array of `UIColor` instances.

```
- (void)animate
{
    [UIView
     animateWithDuration:[_durations[_currentColor] doubleValue]
     animations:^{
         self.view.backgroundColor = _colors[_currentColor++];
     }
     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
         if (_currentColor < _colors.count) {
             [self animate];
         }
         else {
             _currentColor = 0;
         }
     }];
}
```

Comment: Appreciate the code, but given the above discussion, wouldn't large arrays of colors/durations cause the sequence to end (at least slightly) later than it should?

Comment: @ScottyB It may end slightly later